# Splitting a long equation in 2 pieces

Tags: equations, split

I have this equation:

```
\vspace{-2ex}
\begin{equation} \label{TVgen2}
w_q=\min\limits_{w_q}{\left\| w_q \right\|^\alpha + \frac{\beta}{2} \left\|  l \ast f_q-w_q \right\|_2^2} \; \text{for} \; q=1,..,Q.
\end{equation}
```

I have tried to break it in 2 pieces using `multiline` and `split` but none worked.

Does someone has some extra idea how to solve this?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  Please, always post a complete MWE (from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`in order to help us to help you.

Comment: I am using a: \documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

Comment: this works either to me.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you'll have to use the `multline`-environment (there is a letter i missing!).  To use it, add the package `amsmath`.

Here is my example, but I am not sure, if I found the correct breaking point.

It seems important, that you break the formulae at those places, where a complete set of `\left` and `\right` are in one line.  Otherwise LaTeX will complain.

To split the line, insert a double backslash (`\\`) at your favorite point.

Notice, that the `mutline` is a math environment of its own right.  You don't need to put it in an `equation`-environment.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{multline}
  w_q =\min\limits_{w_q} \left\| w_q \right\|^\alpha + %
    \frac{\beta}{2} \\
    \left | l \ast f_q -w_q \right \|_2^2  \quad \text{for} \quad q=1,\ldots,Q.
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

And the outcome

[image: First example using <code>multline</code>-environment]

But I doubt, this is beautifull.  Maybe the `split`-environment is better suited?

Please notice again, that the `split`-environment can only be used inside of a math environment, that is either `$`or `equation` or whatever suits you.  Here you have to use the ampersand `&` to direct the alignment.

I really think, this is working better.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
    w_q =&\min\limits_{w_q} \left\| w_q \right\|^\alpha \\
    &+  \frac{\beta}{2} \left | l \ast f_q -w_q \right \|_2^2  \quad \text{for} \quad q=1,\ldots,Q.
  \end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Now it looks like this:

[image: Second example using <code>split</code>-environment]

One final hint: I used a `\quad`-space, to separate the text more clearly.  Of course, it is a matter of personal taste, how wide the gap should be, but I think, it should not be smaller than a normal space `\`.  Furthermore, use `\ldots` in order to have three lower dots ...

Answer (score 1):

Here are two other possibilities, with `flalign` and with `alignat`. I took the opportunity to define two `\norm` and `\twonorm` commands, with variable delimiters (automatically in the starred version, or with an optional argument: `\big` , `\Big`, &c., if you want to fine-tune their sizes). It uses the `\DeclarePairedDelimiters` family of commands defined in `mathtools`.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran} \usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools, etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}%
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\norm[1]\lVert\rVert{\ifblank{#1}{\: · \:}{#1}}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP{\twonorm }[1]{}{\lVert}{\rVert}{_{2}}{\ifblank{#1}{\: · \:}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[11]
\begin{equation} \label{TVgen2}
  \begin{alignedat}{2}
    w_q & =\min_{w_q}\norm{w_q}^α& + \frac{β}{2} \twonorm{l \ast f_q-w_q } &\\
    & & \text{for} \; q=1,..,Q.&
  \end{alignedat}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[11]
\begin{flalign} \label{TVgen2}
  w_q & =\min_{w_q}\norm{w_q}^α+ \frac{β}{2} \twonorm{l \ast f_q-w_q } & & \text{for} \; q=1,..,Q.\enspace \end{flalign}
  \lipsum[11]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using `multline` seems to give a satisfactory result; well, math in two-column typesetting is always tough.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{multline}\label{TVgen2}
w_q=\min_{w_q} \lVert w_q \rVert^\alpha + 
  \frac{\beta}{2} \lVert l \ast f_q-w_q \rVert_2^2 \\
  \text{for $q=1,\dots,Q$}.
\end{multline}
\lipsum[3]

\begin{itemize}
\item There's no need for \verb|\limits|
\item No need for a brace: \verb|\min_{w_q} X|
\item Don't abuse \verb|\left| and \verb|\right|
\item Use \verb|\dots|, never \verb|...|
\item Don't use \verb|\vspace{-2ex}| before displays
\end{itemize}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Please, note some points:

- There's no need for `\limits`
- No need for a brace: `\min_{w_q} X`
- Don't abuse `\left` and `\right`
- Use `\dots`, never `...`
- Don't use `\vspace{-2ex}` before displays

[image]